# Comparing dates in PHP and return command at specific date + time

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I'm in the process of making wordpress plugin using PHP. The objective is that the plugin will run until a stated date, than it will stop.

The problem is, let say I stated the expired date is on 16/9/2012. The system will only stop the plugin on 17/9/2012 08:00AM. How can I make it stop at 17/9/2012 12:00AM.

The coding that correspond are shown below. Need your advice. Thanks!

```
function display($content) {

$exp_date = "16-09-2012";
$todays_date = date("d-m-Y");

$today = strtotime($todays_date);
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);

if ($expiration_date >= $today) {
    return flag().$content;

} else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `flag()` do here? It is supposed to be stored in a variable and called as `$flag->content`? #NotSure

Comment: `strtotime(date(...))` is basically the same as `time()`. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: can you use [PHP's DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)?

Comment: thanks everyone for the help! @DaveRandom u're right! it's the time zone issue. if I set a specific time zone area, the value will definitely be different in other country. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @SyazwanZubir Base everything on a constant timezone (i.e. UTC). The internet is global and therefore not timezone specific, if you want to time-limit something it's best to base it on a constant. Trying to accurately and independently determine the local time for something like this is a lot of complicated/unreliable code for very little gain. You'll notice that SO doesn't try and work out what time it is where you are, it just uses UTC for everything. That way everyone gets the same read-out no matter where they are and there is much less scope for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use "mktime()" to make timestamp of expiry date. Then you can compare with current time stamp which you can get by function "time()".

For example

```
$exp_date = mktime(23,59,59,9,16,2012);
if(time() > $exp_date){

 // expired

} else {

  // Not expired.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp_date = "16-09-2012";
$todays_date = date("d-m-Y");

$today = strtotime($todays_date); 
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);
```

Can be improved for readability and comfort into

```
$exp_date = "16-09-2012";

$today = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$expiration_date = new DateTime($exp_date,new DateTimezone('UTC');//can be other timezone
```

With DateTime, you can do comparison with >, <, >=, <= like with timestamp, but your using something that has the meaning of "date", not an integer.